# nginx proxy_pass with url rewrite - preserve URL

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, proxypass

I am trying to rewrite url for another domain, main agenda is keep the user in same URL[**dev.gworks.mobi**].

`http://dev.gworks.mobi/openam/*  -> http://frock.gworks.mobi:8080/openam/*`

```
location /openam {

          proxy_pass http://frock.gworks.mobi:8080/;
          proxy_redirect     off;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

it partially works

1. `http://dev.gworks.mobi/openam/ -> http://frock.gworks.mobi:8080/`  [it works]
2. `http://dev.gworks.mobi/openam/XUI/#login/ -> http://frock.gworks.mobi:8080/openam/XUI/#login/`[it does not work]

The reason is `http://dev.gworks.mobi/openam/XUI/#login/` proxy to `http://frock.gworks.mobi:8080//XUI/#login/` instead of `http://frock.gworks.mobi:8080/openam/XUI/#login/`. I'm trying rewrite URL but I'm not successful.

> rewrite ^/openam/(.*)$ /$1 last;

can anyone help me to achieve my use case?

Comment: Your question is confusing - are you trying to remove `openam` from the mapped URI or preserve it?

Comment: `http://dev.gworks.mobi/openam/*`  -> `http://frock.gworks.mobi:8080/openam/*`    it is only my question

Comment: In that case try removing the trailing slash from the proxy_pass statement

Answer (score 0):

Below one is works

```
location /openam {
            proxy_pass http://frock.gworks.mobi:8080/openam;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_buffering off;
}
```